# How to view the state of a git repo using command line

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I use SourceTree mostly to work with git which lets me understand the current state of the repo easily. Given a repo which has lots of branches is it possible or easy to understand the current state of the repo using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Try

```
git status
```

to get brief information about the current status (untracked or changed files). Use

```
git branch -vav
```

to see the list of all branches with some information on them (what remote branches they track and how synchronized with them they are). Use

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

to see the history with branches in colours.